# How to configure multiple queries in wmi_exporter?

Tags: wmi, prometheus, wmi-query, get-wmiobject, wmi-service

> I downloaded the "wmi_exporter-0.7.0-386.exe" from the link [wmi exporter](https://github.com/martinlindhe/wmi_exporter/releases) and ran the '.exe' file using command prompt.

Also i have followed the guidance link [prometheus wmi guidance](https://github.com/martinlindhe/wmi_exporter) to run the command in the command prompt ,it executed as expected and i am able to check the metrics in "http://localhost:9182/metrics".

My problem here is , if i run the command "**./wmi_exporter-0.7.0-386.exe**" alone using the command prompt , i am able to check the memory utilization of my system.For example it is showing the details of the memory utilization like "**wmi_cs_physical_memory_bytes 3.4673408e+10**" and all the memory details as well in browser metrics.

But if i run the command "**.\wmi_exporter.exe --collectors.enabled "process" --collector.process.processes-where "Name LIKE 'firefox%'"**" , in metrics it is filtering only the "**firefox**" browser related things , i am not able to check the system memory utilization details like "**wmi_cs_physical_memory_bytes 3.4673408e+10**".

> Kindly suggest me how to get the system utilization details as well as firefox related details in metrics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add collector query, for all the services which you want to monitor.Like,

msiexec /i C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\wmi_exporter-0.4.3-amd64 ENABLED_COLLECTORS="cpu,cs,logical_disk,os,net,system,process,service,memory" --% EXTRA_FLAGS="--collector.service.services-where ""Name LIKE 'sisense%'"""

Answer (score 0):

> Querying is very simple , just need to add the collector in the query itself,

.\wmi_exporter.exe --collectors.enabled "process,cs,logical_disk" --collector.process.processes-where "Name LIKE 'firefox%'"

> where 'cs' collects local system details , 'logical_disk' collects local drives memory details (such as 'C:\','D:\')

and the "Name LIKE 'firefox'" part collects the fixefox details